# Date convertion between JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I seem not to understand the logic between date conversions client <-> server. I can't find a good way to handle this... Background: my app will run on customers' servers, which I (in general case) will not be able to configure. So I need to find out the PHP time zone offset (it's mostly UTC, but I assume it can be set to any) and the browser's time zone and save timestamps in the databank in the PHP's time zone.

Any help would be appreciated. I have written this:

```
var Time = {
    serverOffset: <?php echo date("Z"); ?>,
    clientOffset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
    serverToClient: function(PHPTimestamp) {
        return PHPTimestamp * 1000 - (Time.clientOffset - Time.serverOffset) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    },
    clientToServer: function(JSDate) {
        var JSTimestamp = +JSDate;
        return JSTimestamp / 1000 + (Time.clientOffset - Time.serverOffset) * 60 * 60;
    },
    midnight: function(D) {
        return D.setHours(0).setMinutes(0).setSeconds(0);
    }    
}
```

but it doesn't work as excepted. For example, if I call Time.clientToServer(new Date()), the resulting timestamp is 2 hours earlier than my local time, but it should be only 1 (my timezone is UTC-1, my PHP is set to UTC).

Still, I guess my approach is NOT the best way to do it. Waiting for tips...

Comment: I timestamp means _Unix_ timestamp here, then the timezone should not be an issue at all – because a Unix timestamp doesn’t _have_ a timezone.

Comment: Server-side time zone is 100% configurable. What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to find a good approach to handle with dates in an app running on servers which I can't configure (it's like a product to install, I have no access to all servers)

Comment: @CBroe you are right. Your posting solves actually my problem. Thanks